# Daydream turns off screen when tapped

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, daydream

I have a daydream enabled, and I have enabled the setting "When to daydream"->"When charging". The daydream starts and displays as expected, but when I tap on the screen to read my notifications, the screen turns completely off rather than turning on and hiding the daydream.

Is there a way to change it so it does not turn off the screen when I tap the daydream? I guess it's a bug...?

I've tried with both the stock clock daydream and a third party one from the store and they behave the same in this manner.

Also - sometimes, this does work (the screen turns on), in exactly the same configuration.

This is on my Nexus 6P with Android 6.0.1

Comment: Happens to me too.